# How to draw rectangles in jsf project?

Tags: javascript, jsf, canvas, primefaces

My project is JSF+PRIMEFACES+JPA and i want to draw rectangles in a jsf web page (XHTML) .

that draw need to be showen after i click on a button based on a list of rectangle that already existe in the managed bean .

its possible to do that just with JSF and primefaces ? or i need to introduce javascript or something else ?

[image]

**Update 1 :**

i fount that richfaces have paint2d option . It'is possible to use just this functionnality from richfaces in my project ?

Comment: Any of the answers worked for you? Then please 'accept' it

Comment: no one of the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="changeColor()" />
        <canvas id='example'>Somewhat</canvas>
        <script>
            var changeColor = function(){
                var colors = ['red' ,'green','blue','yellow','brown','azure','gold'];
                var example = document.getElementById("example"),
                context = example.getContext('2d');
                example.height = 480;
                example.width  = 640;
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
                context.fillStyle = colors[parseInt(Math.random()*colors.length)];
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 7;
                context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                context.stroke();  
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the event onclick need to be in my case in the MANAGED BEAN like **Action=#{#paintmanagedbean.paintrectangle()}**

Comment: i think if you can get access to javascript form java you can invoke it, is not it

Comment: i think isnt possible in jsf :(

Answer (score 1):

Since the 5.1.8 elite release (or the 5.2-SNAPSHOT), Primefaces has the [diagram component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/diagram/basic.xhtml). It can create images you have above, so maybe that is something you cab use

Answer (score 0):

I know that in js one must use canvas. Here simpliest example:
You can write javascript handler to capture click event and then invoke code that image a rectangle

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pathExample</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='example'>Обновите браузер</canvas>
        <script>
            var example = document.getElementById("example"),
                context = example.getContext('2d');
            example.height = 480;
            example.width  = 640;
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 7;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem that the code between <script> need to be dynamique when i click first time in button i need to do a calcule then have my rectangles that i want display.do you know how to do that ?

Comment: try click the button several times